# Bash STRING != STRING not working with string split from `ls`

Tags: bash, ls

I have a bash code which assigns all files into a variable, splits the string by a space and loops over them like this:

```
$ ls
README  db_password.example  db_username.example
```

```
files_str=$(ls)
files=(${files_str// /})

for file in "${files[@]}"; do 
  if [ "$file" != "README" ]; then 
    echo "$file is not README";
  fi; 
done;
```

output:

[image]

I think now that it is something with data types. I thought bash only has strings? I guess I was mislead, maybe by similar sources like this: [https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-5.html#:~:text=There%20are%20no%20data%20types,its%20reference%20will%20create%20it](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-5.html#:%7E:text=There%20are%20no%20data%20types,its%20reference%20will%20create%20it).

But when I do

```
file=README
if [ "$file" != "README" ]; then 
  echo "$file is not README";   
fi;`
```

I get no output which is correct. So how do I make it work with `ls`?

Comment: You probably have an alias for "ls" to add the color, which is produced with additional control chars, which of course mess up the string compare.  Try /bin/ls  or ls --color=none

Comment: Always paste your script into `https://shellcheck.net`, a syntax checker, or install `shellcheck` locally. Make using `shellcheck` part of your development process.

Comment: @ubfan1 you are absolutely right. I have an alias "ls --color" and your suggestion worked, thank you. This is why string didnt compare I guess because color are the character like \e[m etc.. I didn't realise that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have an alias for "ls" to add the color, which is produced with additional control chars, which of course mess up the string compare. Try /bin/ls or ls --color=none instead of just ls.